# Retrieving array list one by one from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, local-storage

I am creating a sample todo application in which I can add/remove tasks but when I refresh the page, data is lost. So I decided to use `localStorage` to save the task lists and retrieve it when page refreshes.

I am able to do the same but I can retrieve the data only as a array list. How can i list tasks one by one stored in my `localStorage` and display it exactly like how it was before page load?

**HTML CODE**

```
<body ng-app="todoApp">
    <div ng-controller="addTaskController" data-ng-init="init()">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>ToDo Application</h3>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <form ng-submit="addTask()" class="form-inline">   
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Task" ng-model="newTask" class="form-control">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</button>
                    <div class="taskList">
                        <ol>
                            <li ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">{{task}} <i style="color:red;margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="deleteTask()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete Task"></i></li> 
                            <p ng-show="tasks.length==0">No Tasks Available </p>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </form> 
          </div>
    </body>
```

**JS CODE**

```
    var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp',[]); 
    todoApp.controller('addTaskController',function($scope){
        $scope.tasks = [];
        $scope.addTask = function() { // Function to add a task to list
            if($scope.newTask == null) {
                alert("Please enter a task");
            } else {
                $scope.tasks.push($scope.newTask);   
                localStorage.setItem("storedTasks", JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
                $scope.newTask = null;   
            }; // add() ends 
        }
        $scope.deleteTask =  function() {
            $scope.tasks.splice(this.$index, 1);
            localStorage.removeItem("storedTasks");
        };
        $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("storedTasks"); 
            if($scope.retrievedData != null) {
                $scope.tasks.push($scope.retrievedData);
            } else {
                tasks.length==0;
            }
        }
    });
```

**Before Page Reload**

[image]

**After Page Reload**

[image]

How can i fix this

Comment: Use also the other way around: `$scope.tasks = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem("storedTasks"));`

Answer (score 2):

`RetrievedData` is an array you have to iterate over and push every item to the `tasks` object. What you are doing now is dumping the whole array into a single task.

```
if($scope.retrievedData != null){
    $scope.retrievedData.forEach(function(item){
        $scope.tasks.push(item);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only store `string` in `local storage`, which you did via `JSON.stringify()`, you need to undo it via [`JSON.parse(text[, reviver])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and then iterate over it.